# When I render, the color changes

Tags: rendering

This is a 2D intro title animation of a couple of solid color geometric figures (rectangles, circles etc.) moving in layers on top of each other, and put the camera right overhead. They are all in purple-ish colors. When I run it with the "play animation" button, the colors are what they should be. But when I render it (ctrl + F12) to a movie, **all the colors are changed** to green-ish colors. It's really only the color of the figures that changes, not the entire video.

When I render each frame to a picture, there is no problem. But there are over 400 frames, so that is impractical.

Comment: Could you add more details to your question? Right now it's hard to tell what you are asking. Perhaps a few screenshots be helpful.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.

Comment: Is it possible you are viewing viewport display colors and actual material diffuse render colors differ from these? Do you have any compositing nodes that might affect outcome?

Comment: There are a lot of reasons this could happen...one is that perhaps you have a colored light or a world background with a color that isn't showing up in the viewport. I'd suggest uploading a simplified version of your file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/.

Comment: @TavernSenses why did you delete the images or the file? The question makes no sense without them now.

Answer (score 8):

As noted by @DuarteFarrajotaRamos you have a node in the compositing that is altering the result.

You have a [Hue Saturation Value](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/color/hue_saturation.html) Node changing your color.

[image]

Comment: Got it, it's under "compositing"