# Why does the 2D animation color look different after rendering?

Tags: rendering, grease-pencil

[image]
This is the solid view and it is supposed to render in the same colour.

[image]
However, the colours change in the render view.
A similar problem can be found at [When I render, the color changes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107072/when-i-render-the-color-changes). I tried but there is nothing to edit in the [Texture Node Editor].
Is there a way to correct the colour?

Comment: I remember something like properties/render/color management/(filmic or srgb) . Also be sure the layers have use light unchecked

Comment: Thank you, I tried to edit all of the parameters in the [Render properties] such as sRGB, exposure and gamma but it does not work. Solved eventually, the colour change is caused by the unintentional use of the tint tool.

Comment: If you solved your problem please write an answer in the answers section, so that other users with a similar issue can learn from you.